# Firestore: Data are Returned Back without the Right Favorite Items Status True or False

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app and I am trying to fetch favorites data from cloud firestore database depending on userId.

The problem is that data are returned back without the right favorite items status true or false.

when I print favoriteData in console, I receive empty map like this: {}

Here is my code and how I tried to achieve this:

```
Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
  var userId = await getCurrentUser();

  final response = await Firestore
      .instance
      .collection("products")
      .getDocuments();

  final favoriteResponse = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("userFavorites")
      .document(userId)
      .collection("MyFavorites")
      .getDocuments();

  final favoriteData = favoriteResponse.documents.asMap();

  try{
    print(favoriteData.toString());
    response.documents.forEach((element) {
      loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: element.documentID,
        title: element.data['title'],
        price: element.data['price'],
        isFavorite: favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[element.documentID] ?? false,
      ));
    });
    _items = loadedProducts;
    notifyListeners();
  }catch(error){
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Here where I call fetchProducts which includes favourited items:

```
class _ProductsScreenState extends State<ProductsScreen> {


var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading =false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if(_isInit){
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      Provider.of<Products>(context,listen: false).fetchProducts().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of documents I am trying to get their value:

[image]

Comment: "data are returned back without the right favorite items status true or false." Can you update your question to: 1) log the wrong value and its output?, 2) include a screenshot of a document that is being wrongfully (not) returned?

Comment: i updated the question as you advised.. hope the info supplied will help you answer my question

Comment: Please update your code snippet to show how/where/when you print `favoriteData`. My initial feeling is that it's something related to the `async` nature. Keep mind that any call to `fetchProducts` needs to `await` the results.

Comment: I updated when I call fetchProducts() which includes favoriteData already

Comment: That looks fine at first glance, so I'm not immediately sure what's going wrong. Can you change toe code to also print `userId` before the query, so that we can whether its value matches the database?

Comment: I print the userId and I received the id in the console which means it can get it: vFKBzWV5VSYIvdSYq8hZbW16EPb2

Comment: That is not the user showing in your screenshot, so you might want to update that. I'd also recommend showing the code that prints and its output in your question. But that's all just troubleshooting tips, since I'm not sure what's going wrong. Hopefully somebody else can spot it with those changes.

Comment: Thank you for trying but it is the same user if you could checkin the screenshot on the left side and the I'd after My Favorites  is I'd of the item itself

Comment: Your code seems fine although I am not an expert in Dart. Could you print the content of `favoriteResponse` right after you perform the firestore query?